# Java Grammar from Github for ANTLR4 and C# target

Tags: java, c#, parsing, antlr4, antlr4cs

I have given up fixing C# grammar from version for ANTLR3.2 to version for ANTLR4, now I want to make Java Parser and Visitor.
The Java grammar for ANTLR4 downloaded from Github: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4 is written for any target language, but some code is for Java target and it does not work with C#. I am talking about these lexar rules:

```
fragment
JavaLetter
:   [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0xFF
|   // covers all characters above 0xFF which are not a surrogate
    ~[\u0000-\u00FF\uD800-\uDBFF]
   // {Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(_input.LA(-1))}?
|   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
    [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
    //{Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char) _input.LA  (-1)))}?
;

fragment
JavaLetterOrDigit
:   [a-zA-Z0-9$_] // these are the "java letters or digits" below 0xFF
|   // covers all characters above 0xFF which are not a surrogate
    ~[\u0000-\u00FF\uD800-\uDBFF]
   // {Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(_input.LA(-1))}?
|   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
    [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
    //{char.isJavaIdentifierPart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
;
```

I have commented the target codes starting with **{Character.isJavaIdentifier...}** and it is now OK. I was wondering why is it there!? I think it returns true if the token before or 2 tokens before (in case LA(-2)) are IdentifierPart, but what is the action code for? In C# **Char** object does not support static method isIdentifierPart or something like that...

**My question is:** If I cancel the action code, will the parser fail on a specific identifier name during the parsing of a Java input code?
If YES, how can I substitute it for C# target?

Thanks for replies!
PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Java Language Specification §3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), an *identifier* is defined in terms of two static methods on the `Character` class.

> > ```
> > Identifier:
> >   IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
> >
> > IdentifierChars:
> >   JavaLetter {JavaLetterOrDigit}
> >
> > JavaLetter:
> >   any Unicode character that is a "Java letter"
> >
> > JavaLetterOrDigit:
> >   any Unicode character that is a "Java letter-or-digit"
> > ```
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)` returns true.

The grammar implements this in a specific manner designed to maximize performance for the expected inputs. In particular, the most well known characters from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]` (Regular Expression syntax) are handled directly by the grammar. The language specification guarantees that this set will always be considered identifier characters.

ANTLR 4 does not cache DFA transitions for UTF-16 code units above U+007F, so anything outside the previously described set is on a "slow" path for the lexer anyway. Rather than bloat the size of the state machine, these characters are handled using a clean and simple semantic predicate.

If your source code does not use code points above U+007F for Unicode identifiers, then you can safely reduce the grammar to the following:

```
fragment
JavaLetter
  :   [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0xFF
  ;

fragment
JavaLetterOrDigit
  :   [a-zA-Z0-9$_] // these are the "java letters or digits" below 0xFF
  ;
```

Otherwise, for complete support you can use the [**Java-LR.g4**](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime.Test/Java-LR.g4) grammar from the C# target (rename to **Java.g4** before using).

Comment: Java-LR.g4 - does it mean, that it written for LR(1) parser? But LL(*) should parse it anyway, right? So the reason of this alternative ~[\u0000-\u00FF\uD800-\uDBFF]... is different encoding of an input to parse (UTF-16 for example)?

Comment: "LR" stands for "left recursive". This version of the grammar uses a left-recursive `expression` rule rather than write out the full precedence hierarchy as separate rules.